# Turtle Graphics Moving Square

Tags: python, python-turtle

I drew a square in Python with turtle. I would like to be able to pan the square in compass directions (N,S,E,W) with the w, a, s, d keys. I drew up a solution, but it runs very slowly, and there is a strange error where it stops drawing squares. I'm not really sure where I went wrong. Is there a better solution that runs well? Is there a correction to my solution to solve the issues with moving around the canvas?

```
import turtle
import screen

cube = turtle.Turtle()
cube.hideturtle()
cube.speed(0)

unit = 5
width = 10 * unit
height = 10 * unit
length = 10 * unit
turn = 90
posiX = -100
posiY = 100

def start():
    global posiX
    global posiY
    cube.up()
    cube.setposition(posiX,posiY)
    cube.down()
    cube.hideturtle()

def topView():
    start()
    for i in range(2):
        cube.forward(width)
        cube.right(turn)
        cube.forward(height)
        cube.right(turn)

def panW():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY - unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
    turtle.update()
def panA():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX + unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
    turtle.update()
def panS():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY + unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
    turtle.update()
def panD():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX - unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
    turtle.update()
    
window = turtle.Screen


topView()

turtle.onkey(panW, "w")
turtle.onkey(panA, "a")
turtle.onkey(panS, "s")
turtle.onkey(panD, "d")



turtle.listen()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I notice that the code draws each square really slowly, and as width and height is the same you could make them the same variable. To fix it:

```
#At the start
turtle.tracer(0, 0)               #Disable automatic refresh
unit = 5                        #Same as earlier
side = unit*10                  #One side is the same as both width and height
def topVieW():                  #Define topView
    start()                     #Use start()
    for i in range(4):          #Repeat once for each side
         cube.forward(side)     #Forward your side
         cube.right(90)         #A square has to have 90 degree angle
    cube.update()               #Refresh screen
```

Not constantly refreshing the screen significantly improves the speed of the program.

I also notice that your square moves left when I press d. To fix this, simply change the pan functions. You also don't need an update in every pan function, especially not when you haven't disabled the auto updating. Updating in topView is also shortening the code by 3 lines.
The pan functions should be this:

```
def panW():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY + unit        #Now it moves upward
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panA():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX - unit       #Now it moves to the left
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panS():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY - unit       #Now it moves downward
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panD():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX + unit       #Now it moves to the right
    cube.reset()
    topView()
```

As you do not use start() anywhere else than in topView(), so you could put the contents of start() within topView. That makes topView like this:

```
def topVieW():
    global posiX
    global posiY
    cube.up()
    cube.goto(posiX, posiY)
    cube.down()
    for i in range(4):
         cube.forward(side)
         cube.right(90)
    cube.update()
```

After implementing this, it should no longer be an issue that the turtle draws several squares on top of each other.
If you also want the square to move as long as you hold down the button, you could add this instead of your turtle.onkey statements:

```
def pressing(button, action):
    turtle.onkeypress(action, button)
    turtle.onkeyrelease(action, button)
pressing("w", panW)
pressing("a", panA)
pressing("s", panS)
pressing("d", panD)
```

So the total code is:

```
import turtle
import screen

cube = turtle.Turtle()
cube.hideturtle()
cube.speed(0)

turtle.tracer(0, 0)
unit = 5
side = unit*10 
length = 10 * unit
turn = 90
posiX = -100
posiY = 100

def topView():
    global posiX
    global posiY
    cube.up()
    cube.goto(posiX, posiY)
    cube.down()
    for i in range(4):
         cube.forward(side)
         cube.right(90)
    turtle.update()
    turtle.hideturtle()

def panW():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY + unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panA():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX - unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panS():
    global posiY
    posiY = posiY - unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
def panD():
    global posiX
    posiX = posiX + unit
    cube.reset()
    topView()
    
window = turtle.Screen

topView()

def pressing(button, action):
    turtle.onkeypress(action, button)
    turtle.onkeyrelease(action, button)
    
pressing("w", panW)
pressing("a", panA)
pressing("s", panS)
pressing("d", panD)

turtle.listen()
turtle.done()
```

Unfortunately, I did not manage to get the turtle to hide properly.
Let me know if it helped!

Regards,
norway-yv